# Calculate time of executing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to calculate the time of executing some process. For example i want to read all lines from a file, but if it's going more than 5 sec, to show messagebox, for example.  How and what timer should i create, to handle this "5 sec"?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31691/Timeout-Functions#execute_within_timelimit

Comment: Kick the read-file off to a new thread and in the main thread keep track of the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool result = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomePossibleFailingTask).Wait(1000);

        if (result == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something has gone wrong!");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void SomePossibleFailingTask()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
long time=0;

bool b = Task.Factory
            .StartNew(() => time = ExecutionTime(LongRunningTask))
            .Wait(5000);

if (b == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Execution took more than 5 seconds.");
}

//time contains the execution time in msec.
```

---

```
public long ExecutionTime(Action action)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

public void LongRunningTask()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class: (part of System.Diagnostics namespace)

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
while (someCond) {
    if (watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 5) {
        MessageBox.Show("Process taking too much time, aborting");
        break;
    }
    //keep looping
}
watch.Stop();
string msg = "Process took " + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds to complete"
```

Comment: @ProkopchukVitaliy you said "I need to calculate the time of executing some process" and that's what I answered. I will answer your other question shortly.

Comment: thank you, but i think, it will work only for loops. Im not able to do loops in all cases i need to calculate execution time

Answer (score 0):

```
long time1;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
...
time = sw.ElapsedTicks;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostic
using System.Window.Forms

//your code
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

// start reading lines of a file using file system object

watch.Stop();

if(watch.Elapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds>5000)
{
   MessageBox.Show("The process takes more than 5 seconds !!!");
}
else
{
   // your business logic
}
```

Comment: it seems to check time, only after the lines were read, and i need  to do it like a "simulteniously"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = new Task(YourLongRunningOperation, cts.Token);
task.Start();

var delayTask = Task.Delay(5000);

try
{
    await Task.WhenAny(task, delayTask);
    if(!task.IsCompleted)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        // You can display a message here.
        await task;
    }
}
catch(OperationCanceledException cex)
{
    // TODO Handle cancelation.
}
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
    // TODO Handle exceptions.
}

if(task.IsCanceled && delayTask.IsCompleted)
{
    // TODO Display a long running error message.
}
```